# Border not surrounding box

Tags: html, css

I want to know why the border that I have defined for a child `div` is not enclosing the element. I have defined two boxes using `div` tags and I am applying a border to the child div element.

```css
    #box {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    
    #upper-half {
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
```

```html
       <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Height and width percentages</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="box">
          <div id="upper-half">
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The border that you see doesn't fully enclose the box "upper half".

To investigate this I used the browsers page inspector and it appears that the dimension of the box is 509.2 x 259.2.

I have several questions at this point:-

1. Why is the box size: 509.2 x 259.2 even when the padding is zero?
2. Why is the border not enclosing the box?
3. Why is the border flush against the left hand side, top & bottom of the box (expected) but not the right hand side?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add **box-sizing: border-box;**

The **default value** of box-sizing is **content-box**, it sums the width of the borders to the content width. Setting it's value as **border-box** it will calculate the total width including the borders

```css
    #box {
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    
    #upper-half {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
```

```html
       <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Height and width percentages</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="box">
          <div id="upper-half">
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

For more info, check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `width:100%` on the inner box. See example below.

```css
#box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: orange;
}
    
#upper-half {
  height: 50%;
  

  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="upper-half">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are very confusing since you literally have defined one box: #box. But here is an attempt to answer them:

1. Your #box is 500px x 500px as specified in your CSS
2. The #upper-half is not enclosing #box because you have defined it as 50% x 100% of the enclosing `div` that is #box, so it will be 250px x 500px
3. The `border` specification is not included in total height or width calculations, so will go beyond the 50% x 100% you were expecting. It is 'flush' against the left and top of #box only because by default the DOM aligns objects to the left and top. It is not 'flush' against the bottom or right of #box because you have not told it to be, merely given it height and width instructions.

As @Damian Peralta pointed out, using `box-sizing: border-box;` on #upper-half to properly 'bound' it within #box will work.